How do I deserialize JSON where fieldName itself is part of the value?
I have a JSON payload that contains the field name as part of the JSON field's value.
JSON Payload:
{
  "results": [
      {
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldName": "employeeId",
                "value": "123"
            },
            {
                "fieldName": "name",
                "value": "John"
            },
            {
                "fieldName": "salary",
                "value": 100023
            },
            {
                "fieldName": "isDifferentlyAbled",
                "value": true
            },
            {
                "fieldName": "weight",
                "value": 10.12
            }
            ... // more fields, around 15
         ]
     },
     {
        ...  // 2nd node
     }
   ]
}

I can deserialize it by converting the payload by using ObjectMapper and by writing a logic to iterate over ArrayNode and performing conditional checks such as:
if (fieldNameNode.asText().equals("employeeId")) {
  employee.setId(fieldValueNode.asText());
}

However, as the payload contains roughly 15 fields this solution is not elegant. is there a way to deserialize such payload elegantly using the library itself? or by using any design pattern?

Who wrote that JSON? Knowing nothing about why it was written that way, I would say it is structured badly.

Also, since this is an array of Fields, I would think that you could use Streams to get the result you want. I don't have much experience with Jackson, so I am just guessing.

You may try to use JSON library Josson to transform your payload into the desired format of Jackson JsonNode first.
https://github.com/octomix/josson
POJO Employee
public static class Employee {
    @JsonProperty(value = "employeeId")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Double salary;

    private Boolean differentlyAbled;

    private Double weight;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Boolean isDifferentlyAbled() {
        return differentlyAbled;
    }

    public void isDifferentlyAbled(Boolean differentlyAbled) {
        this.differentlyAbled = differentlyAbled;
    }

    public Double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

Deserialize
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"results\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "        \"fields\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"employeeId\"," +
    "                \"value\": \"123\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"name\"," +
    "                \"value\": \"John\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"salary\"," +
    "                \"value\": 100023" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"isDifferentlyAbled\"," +
    "                \"value\": true" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"weight\"," +
    "                \"value\": 10.12" +
    "            }" +
    "         ]" +
    "     }," +
    "      {" +
    "        \"fields\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"employeeId\"," +
    "                \"value\": \"456\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"name\"," +
    "                \"value\": \"Marry\"" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"salary\"," +
    "                \"value\": 123456" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"isDifferentlyAbled\"," +
    "                \"value\": false" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"fieldName\": \"weight\"," +
    "                \"value\": 8.34" +
    "            }" +
    "         ]" +
    "     }" +
    "   ]" +
    "}");

Transform and Convert
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("results@.fields.mergeObjects(map(fieldName::value))");
System.out.println("\nJsonNode:\n" + node.toPrettyString());

List<Employee> employees = Josson.convertValue(node);
System.out.println("\nList<Employee>:\n" + employees);

Transformation expression:

results@ : The modifier @ at the end of an array node divert each element to separate branch for upcoming manipulation.
mergeObjects() : Merge multiple objects into one object.
map() : Construct an object.  Double colon :: extract the field value to become the key name.

Output
JsonNode:
[ {
  "employeeId" : "123",
  "name" : "John",
  "salary" : 100023,
  "isDifferentlyAbled" : true,
  "weight" : 10.12
}, {
  "employeeId" : "456",
  "name" : "Marry",
  "salary" : 123456,
  "isDifferentlyAbled" : false,
  "weight" : 8.34
} ]

List<Employee>:
[{employeeId=123, name=John, salary=100023, isDifferentlyAbled=true, weight=10.12}, {employeeId=456, name=Marry, salary=123456, isDifferentlyAbled=false, weight=8.34}]


@Raymod Choi This is neat. can we achieve the same thing with bare metal Jackson API?

@GovindaSakhare I don't think Jackson has API to transform JSON this way.
